# How is the sin function being rewritten?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I'm working through a trigonometry book and was shown this equation being worked out.  I don't understand the rules for doing a particular step:

$$\begin{align}
A &= A\sin(x-vt) \\
1 &= \sin(x-vt) \\
x-vt &= {\pi \over 2} \\
x &= {\pi \over 2}+vt
\end{align}$$

How are they going from $1=\sin(x-vt)$ to $x-vt = {\pi \over 2}$?  Thanks!

Comment: For what value(s) of $A$ is $\sin (A) = 1$?

Comment: I think it will all become clear when I tell you that $\arcsin(1) = \frac{\pi}{2}$. To reiterate, just take the $\arcsin$ of both sides.

Comment: @recursiverecursion $\arcsin(\sin(x))$ does not always equal $x$!

Comment: true, but it would only make sense if it did in this case. This is generally a strategy one should employ when trying to understand a step like this.

Comment: Something more should be known about $x-vt$ to justify the step in question, because as mentioned in @rogerl's answer, the equation has other solutions. This looks like a physics problem, so probably some bounds for $x-vt$ are known.

Comment: It is physics related, it's dealing with the crest of a wave moving at velocity v, x being the crest.

Comment: I believe in this context, it isn't that important which of the periodic solutions for $ \ x \ $ is used.  That's why there aren't any bounds stated in this (out-of-context) excerpt.

Comment: @recursiverecursion interesting, what textbook is this from if you dont mind me asking?

Comment: Trigonometry the Easy Way.  Not sure if it's a great book, but it goes over a lot of areas where trigonometry is used so that if you're interested in diving deeper you can.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whenever you confront a step like this, notice that the $\sin$ is being taken off one side. That means that the inverse of the $\sin$ function must have been used. From this reasoning, even if you don't know that $\arcsin(1) = \frac{\pi}{2}$, then you can make the logical assumption that it is, and from that you can understand the step.
EDIT:
Note that $\arcsin(\sin(x))$ does **not** always equal $x$. I would not use this step in trying to solve an equation, but for something like this, the strategy shown above helps.

Comment: For whatever reason it didn't dawn on me to try and do that. Thanks, totally clear now.

Comment: I think this is a bit dangerous explanation, because it's a common error to "solve" trigonometric equations by using "inverse function" ($\sin$ and $\cos$ don't have inverse functions).

Comment: You're right, let me edit it to emphasize that.

Answer (score 7):

To solve the equation $1 = \sin(x-vt)$, you must ask yourself: what angle $\theta$ is such that $\sin\theta = 1$? One such angle is $\frac{\pi}{2}$. (The others are $\frac{\pi}{2} \pm 2n\pi$).

Comment: $\sin(3\pi/2) = -1$; I think you mean $\pi/2 +- 2\pi n$?

Comment: D'oh. Of course I did.  Thanks.

Comment: Also, crucially, these are the _only_ angles $\theta$ such that $\sin\theta=1$; this is the fact that allows us to take the equation the 'other direction' and say that if we have $\sin\theta=1$ then $\theta$ must be of this form.

Comment: I'm not sure how to mark both as accepted answers.  Both of these totally helped but the other one went into more of how I was failing in reasoning through it.  Thanks!